# performance of sharepoint 2010 is slow (having cent os)

Tags: centos

we have Production Application Server (INSPRODSP ram 20GB) and Database server (INSPRODDB RAM 32GB)) are two VM s on a physical box. The box has an operating system Cent OS (Unix based). This system has 64 GB RAM and 10 CPUs.

12 GB of RAM and 2 CPU s are not in use.
THEN CAN YOU SUGGEST ME REASON Y  PERFORMANCE OF SHAREPOINT SITE IS VERY LOW?

Comment: CentOS is Linux, not Unix.

Answer (score 0):

PLEASE DON'T USE ALL CAPS IN RANDOM SENTENCES.

Now that that's taken care of. You don't mention your disk layout. I can only assume that they share the same underlying spindles. If that's the case, you're likely seeing I/O contention here. SharePoint is an I/O beast. The database should have many dedicated spindles, as should any application/frontend servers. Sharing them is a recipe for disaster.

---

Side Note: Why are you using CentOS as a host OS (with KVM, I assume) for only two Windows servers? Why not use something like Hyper-V Server or another bare-metal hypervisor.

Comment: i just wanted to ask wheather Cent os affect performance?

Comment: Of course it has the potential to affect performance. If you're asking if I know whether or not your specific host OS configuration is affecting your VMs, then you need to re-read your question and realize that you've provided *no* details for anyone to possibly answer that.

Comment: HostName C Drivesize D DriveSize   OS         RAM      CPU  INSPRODSP  100GB  100GB  | Windows 2008 stdR2 64bit 20GB     4 INSPRODDB  100GB  1300GB | Windows 2008 stdR2 64bit 32GB 4

Comment: That's unintelligible. Honestly, I think you might be a bit over your head. Perhaps you should hire a consultant for some training and to help sort out your issue. It looks like you're trying to post some disk info, but my answer wasn't about the guest disk layout, but rather about the underlying disk geometry on the host.